# Get the second section of numbers from an IP address

Tags: powershell

I need to get the second section of an IP address stored in a variable for comparison reasons.

$a = "10.20.0.0"

I need to get and store the 20 as a new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Split to get what you need

```
$a.Split('.')[1]
```

This splits on the '.' and then you can access each section starting from 0.